# Sync Headers, Body and Tests in Postman

Tags: postman

I'm using postman for linux (v9.18.2) on Pop!_OS (20.04) and sync my collections between devices via the built-in sync function. The green cloud icon indicates "In sync".

However, I couldn't find how to sync the body, tests, headers etc. too.

Does anyone know if this can be done somehow?

Comment: How do you sync your collections?

Comment: I use the built-in sync function from the application. The green cloud icon indicates "In sync".